# Limit Comparison test, is my use of it correct?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

find if $\frac{\sqrt{1+n}}{n+4}$ converges or diverges

I use the limit comparison test with $a_n$ being the above fraction and $b_n$ being $\frac{\sqrt{1+n}}{n}$

I then do ${\frac{a_n}{b_n}}$ and cross-cancel, being left with $\frac{n}{n+4}$, which has a limit of 1

because the limit of the division is positive and finite, and because the limit of $b_n$ is a divergent series I can say that $a_n$ is divergent by the limit comparison test

Comment: how do you come from $$\frac{a_n}{b_n}$$ to $\frac{n}{n+4}$?

Comment: sorry that was a mistake on my part edited it now

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Comment: it was edited now